# First time Automatically login

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm creating chat app where I added register/login functionality with firebase, but whenever I clear all the data and registered user from firebase console and uninstall the app from my device and install once again from fresh starting, it directly go to main activity (means where user can go after register/login) instead of asking register/login (which is start activity). How?

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.jimmytrivedi.lapitchat;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser currentUser;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private DatabaseReference UserDatabaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.mainToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (currentUser == null) {
            sendTostart();
        } else {
            UserDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
            UserDatabaseReference.child("Online").setValue(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            UserDatabaseReference.child("Online").setValue(false);
        }
    }

    private void sendTostart() {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.logout) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            sendTostart();
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.allUsers) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, UsersActivity.class));
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

**StartActivity.java**

```
package com.jimmytrivedi.lapitchat;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button signup, exist;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        signup = findViewById(R.id.signup);
        exist = findViewById(R.id.exist);

        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class));
            }
        });

        exist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Updated code but still same issue:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.jimmytrivedi.lapitchat;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser currentUser;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private DatabaseReference UserDatabaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.mainToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (currentUser == null) {
            sendTostart();
        } else {
            UserDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
            UserDatabaseReference.child("Online").setValue(true);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            UserDatabaseReference.child("Online").setValue(false);
        }
    }

    private void sendTostart() {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.logout) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            sendTostart();
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.allUsers) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, UsersActivity.class));
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: think of the flow of this. on app start, the first activity is MainActivity. Within main activity, onCreate (not onStart) if user is not signed in, send them to another activity. i think your logic is wrong. you need to move everyting from your onStart to on Create. at the top right after the layout business. move the currentUser above that.

Comment: I did that, it was working fine yesterday. But now again same problem. See the code, I edited the question and updated the code as you suggested

Comment: And please solve my another problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51217291/blank-friendsfragment

Comment: I have observed that it is not going to if() part! don't know why?